# How do I use Confluence's servlet-filter module?

Tags: servlet-filters, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I have recently become aware of Confluence's servlet-filter module. However, after trying to get it to work, I have run into a dead end. I am getting my information here:

https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/confluence-plugin-module-types/servlet-filter-module

Here is what I tried. I annotated my atlassian-plugin.xml file like so:

```
<servlet-filter name="My Test Filter" key="OURAPP" class="com.test.filters.HelloWorldFilter" location="after-encoding" weight="100">
    <description>Forwards you to a test "Hello, world!" page.</description>
    <url-pattern>/helloworld</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</servlet-filter>
```

Then, I created a standard Java servlet (extends HttpServlet, etc.) at com/test/filters called HelloWorldFilter.java. In the "doGet()" method, I simply have a System.out.println() line that reads "IN THE FILTER". However, when I go to the following URLs, I always get the "Page Not Found" error page:

http://127.0.0.1:8090/helloworld

http://127.0.0.1:8090/OURAPP/helloworld

http://127.0.0.1:8090/plugins/OURAPP/helloworld

http://127.0.0.1:8090/rest/helloworld

http://127.0.0.1:8090/rest/OURAPP/helloworld

http://127.0.0.1:8090/OURAPP/rest/helloworld

We have a custom Confluence plugin, lets call it OURAPP, that is serving up data not only through the browser GUI, but also through Confluence's REST capabilities. I am trying to create a filter that manages valid and invalid requests alike. We can access the REST at:

http://127.0.0.1:8090/rest/reststuff/v1/some_function_here

Like I said in the beginning, I have run into a dead end here, and cannot figure out how to get this to work. Can anybody offer up any suggestions or example code of how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of days messing around with this, I FINALLY figured out what was wrong. I was extending `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` instead of implementing `javax.servlet.Filter`. After I changed to implementing Filter, and implemented all the proper methods, my servlet filter started to work at `127.0.0.1:8090/helloworld`. There are a number of examples out there that use a standard Java Servlet (i.e., extending HttpServlet) but that [apparently] does not work with Confluence. I hope this helps somebody else out there struggling with Confluence's confusion. Thanks to all who took the time to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatcher tag is missing the closing ">":

```
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher
```

Regards,
Gorka

Comment: Not really ... I simply forgot to add it when I transcribed the code.

Comment: Could you add your log to check if there're errors?

Comment: After a couple of days messing around with this, I FINALLY figured out what was wrong. I was extending javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet instead of implementing javax.servlet.Filter. After I changed to implementing Filter, and implemented all the proper methods, my servlet filter started to work at http://127.0.0.1:8090/helloworld . Thanks for taking a look at this issue for me!